# Unable to find long string in array string - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, contains

I'm trying to find a long string in another string. For this I've been using **G[i].Contains(P[arr])** but for some reason the code just skips that condition. In my case : G[I] is 1000 character long and P[arr] is 475. When I debug I can see strings are not trimmed and also I have verified that P[ARR] is part of G[I] in Notepad++ so it should definitely satisfy a condition.

```
        for (int arr = 0; arr < P.Length; arr++)
        {
            for (int i = a; i < G.Length; i++)
            {
                if (G[i].Contains(P[arr]))
                {
                    if (!(b == 0))
                    {
                        a = i + 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    primary_1 = (a == 0) ? G[i].IndexOf(P[arr]) : primary;
                    ++count;
                    a = i + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The loop for `i` is initialised to be `a`... but that isn't mentioned... should that be `arr`? (also occurs elsewhere)

Comment: What are initial values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Also what's your real goal here? If you want to find a string in another string, why not just do `A.Contains(B)` where `A` and `B` are your two strings?

Comment: As you can see, the formatting will work when your code is indented, so you don't need the back-quotes at the start and end. Also note that the star star won't embolden code, so you probably want to remove that. Don't worry... you can press the [edit] button under your question to fix this.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your quick responses. Basically , I'm just trying to find P[arr] in G[i] but the problem is that G[i] is 1000 character long and P[arr] is 475. So, my assumption is that there might be length limitation for Contains method? As if both strings are much shorter it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: You still aren't very clear. Are `G` and `P` simple strings (which means they are `char` arrays) or are they string arrays? Next, you haven't said what the initial values of `a` and `b` are. Please answer those questions, and also show your sample input and output.

Comment: @Sach - These are string[] G, string[] P the example are huge but I can provide here a shortened version - this is G[i] - 649878239947538712104652760661359717721422234065538127 and this is P[arr] - 947538712104652. So, in the example it should satisfy my condition and go inside of the first "if". Initial value of a is 0 please ignore b at this stage. My main query is with if condition  - if (G[i].Contains(P[arr])) where I don't understand why it is skipping it.

Comment: In that case I can't reproduce your error. See here https://dotnetfiddle.net/YwJXHf
I think it's possible your `a` is set to some other value than `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping with this. Appears to be my string contained some whitespaces, so I added Trim() method which solved that issue.